# discord.js certain channel embed

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know how to make it where if you drop an image in a certain channel, it turns into an embed.

My current code is this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'icon',
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if(message.channel.id === '708914703338045491'){
        message.delete();
        let usermsg = args.slice(0).join(" ");

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#2f3136")
        .setImage(usermsg);

        message.delete().catch();
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you upload image into message it's will save into `message.attachments`, so you can use this collection to check. Discord attachment can be a file, or video, so you need to check file format, the simple  way - it's check end of the link to the content in it of a valid format, so i create 2 function.

- First: for find attachment
- Second: for validate url to content an image format in url

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const avalibleFormats = ['png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg']
module.exports = {
    name: 'icon',
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if (message.channel.id !== '708914703338045491') {
            return;
        }

        let image = getImage(message)
        if (!image) {
            return;
        }

        let embed = new MessageEmbed();
        embed.setImage(image.url)
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}

const getImage = (message) => message.attachments.find(attachment => checkFormat(attachment.url))
const checkFormat = (url) => avalibleFormats.some(format => url.endsWith(format))
```

Comment: so you can use this as fucntion and add to `bot.on('message` block. You give this code, so i use your template.